# Get real screen resolution using Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to get the real screen resolution, that is the resolution that actual output by the gpu, for each of the multiple screen, without affecting by dpi settings.
I tried many answers from SO, but none of them seems to handle it correctly.

Some of the answers I tried:

- [Is GetScaleFactorForMonitor winapi returning incorrect scaling factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692872/is-getscalefactorformonitor-winapi-returning-incorrect-scaling-factor) Calling `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext()` or `SetProcessApiAware()` does not help, `GetScaleFactorForMonitor()` never returns the correct scale factor for anything other than 100% dpi.

-`GetDpiForMonitor()` also does not return the correct dpi. And the `dpiX` and `dpiY` it returns does not even match.

Code:

```cpp
static int result = []() {SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE); return 1; }(); //nope

struct MonitorInfo
{
    MONITORINFO m_moniforInfo;
    UINT dpiX{};
    UINT dpiY{};
};

static std::vector<MonitorInfo> monitors;

BOOL EnumProc(HMONITOR monitor, HDC _, LPRECT __, LPARAM ___)
{
    MONITORINFO monitorInfo{ sizeof(MONITORINFO) };
    GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &monitorInfo);
    UINT dpix;
    UINT dpiy;
    GetDpiForMonitor(monitor, MDT_RAW_DPI, &dpix, &dpiy);
    monitors.push_back(MonitorInfo{ monitorInfo, dpix, dpiy});
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE); //nope
    EnumDisplayMonitors(nullptr, nullptr, EnumProc, 0);
    for (auto const& monitor : monitors)
    {
        auto width = monitor.m_moniforInfo.rcMonitor.right - monitor.m_moniforInfo.rcMonitor.left;
        auto height = monitor.m_moniforInfo.rcMonitor.bottom - monitor.m_moniforInfo.rcMonitor.top;
        std::cout << width << " x " << height << '\t' << "dpix: " << monitor.dpiX << '\t' << monitor.dpiY << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output, comments in (parens)

```
2560 x 1440     dpix: 108       109  (this is 3840*2160 with 150% scale)
2560 x 1440     dpix: 109       109  (this is 2560*2160 with 100% scale)
1920 x 1080     dpix: 163       106  (this is 3840*2160 with 200% scale)
1080 x 1920     dpix: 90        89   (this is 1080*1920 with 100% scale, shouldn't it be 96d?)
1920 x 1080     dpix: 163       106 (this is 3840*2160 with 200% scale too)
```

Comment: Make sure the manifest of your app is properly setup otherwise your calls may not return reality, this is by design. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows

Comment: @SimonMourier It's a C++ console application. With this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process#setting-default-awareness-programmatically I tried both setting api-awareness in first line of `main` or setting it in global scope with some tricks. None works

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't. It's practically impossible to know what's going on if you aren't sharing a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable Okay I added those two tries

Comment: `PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE` is exactly the wrong flag to use, as it means the system will lie to you. `PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE` will give you the true dimensions of all your monitors.

Comment: Literally the first comment to this question links to documentation that explains in excruciating detail how DPI-awareness works and what the different DPI-awareness modes mean. It remains a mystery to anyone why you decided to announce to the system that your application is DPI-unaware and then go ahead and ask why the system treats your application as DPI-unaware.

Answer (score 3):

The following answer was tested with `SetProcessDPIAware()` and without.
In all cases, it gave the correct values.

I did not found it anywhere on the internet so I am glad to share my knowledge with the world.

### To get real monitor resolution

```cpp
void GetMonitorRealResolution(HMONITOR monitor, int* pixelsWidth, int* pixelsHeight)
{
    MONITORINFOEX info = { sizeof(MONITORINFOEX) };
    winrt::check_bool(GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &info));
    DEVMODE devmode = {};
    devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    winrt::check_bool(EnumDisplaySettings(info.szDevice, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devmode));
    *pixelsWidth = devmode.dmPelsWidth;
    *pixelsHeight = devmode.dmPelsHeight;
}
```

It will return that native resolution in any case, even if the OS tries to lie to you due to the DPI awareness of the process.

### To get the scaling ratio between the virtual resolution and real resolution

```cpp
float GetMonitorScalingRatio(HMONITOR monitor)
{
    MONITORINFOEX info = { sizeof(MONITORINFOEX) };
    winrt::check_bool(GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &info));
    DEVMODE devmode = {};
    devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    winrt::check_bool(EnumDisplaySettings(info.szDevice, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devmode));
    return (info.rcMonitor.right - info.rcMonitor.left) / static_cast<float>(devmode.dmPelsWidth);
}
```

This will give you a ratio of the real resolution relative to the virtual resolution of the given monitor.

If the main DPI of the main monitor is 225% and on the second monitor it is 100%, and you run this function for the second monitor, you will get 2.25. because `2.25 * real resolution` = `the virtual resolution` of the monitor.

If the second monitor has 125% scaling (while the main monitor is still 225% scaling), then this function will return you `1.79999995` because 125% relative to 225% is this value (225/125 = 1.8), and again - 1.8 * real resolution`=`the virtual resolution of 125%`

### To get the real DPI value (not relative to anything)

Given that monitor, A has 225% DPI, and monitor B has 125% DPI, as I said above, you will not get 1.25 for the second monitor (if you run the function on the second monitor. You will get 1.8 as I said).

To overcome this, use this function:

```cpp
float GetRealDpiForMonitor(HMONITOR monitor)
{
    return GetDpiForSystem() / 96.0 / GetMonitorScalingRatio(monitor);
}
```

This function depends on the previous function that I wrote above (the function `GetMonitorScalingRatio` that you need to copy)

This will give you the correct value.

Comment: Brilliant! This really works! EnumDisplaySettings does provide the native resolution and this is the only way that I was able to get the correct display scaling (GetScaleFactorForMonitor gives it wrong).

Comment: can you help to write this in c code?

Comment: Yes,i need in this help too,because i dont know,how to use winrt::check_bool function in c code